# Hide scale bar on label click in Charts.js

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, charts, chart.js

I have a simple Charts.js Line Chart with two datasets (lines).
When I click on one of the legend labels, the visibility of the lines in the chart is toggled, but the vertical scale bar still appears. My question is how to make the vertical scale bar to shown and hidden alongside to the line?

```
var data = {
    labels: [1, 2, 3, 4],
    datasets: [
        {
            label: "(Mbps) UP",
            fill: false,
            yAxisID: "y-axis-upstream",
            backgroundColor: "#98B954",
            borderColor: "#98B954",
            pointBorderColor: "#98B954",
            pointBackgroundColor: "#fff",
            pointHoverBackgroundColor: "#98B954",
            pointHoverBorderColor: "#98B954",
            data: [1, 2, 3, 4]
        },
        {
            label: "(Mbps) DOWN",
            fill: false,
            yAxisID: "y-axis-downstream",
            backgroundColor: "#BE4B48",
            borderColor: "#BE4B48",
            pointBorderColor: "#BE4B48",
            pointBackgroundColor: "#fff",
            pointHoverBackgroundColor: "#BE4B48",
            pointHoverBorderColor: "#BE4B48",
            data: [10, 22, 33, 43]
        }
    ]
};
var options = {
    title: {
        display: true,
        text: "Chart Title"
    },
    legend: {
        display: true,
        position: "top"
    },
    scales: {
        yAxes: [
            {
                id: "y-axis-upstream",
                type: "linear",
                display: true,
                position: "left",
                stepSize: 0.1,
                fixedStepSize: 0.1,
                gridLines: {
                    color: "rgba(152, 185, 84, 0.4)"
                },
                ticks: {
                    display: true,
                    fontColor: "#98B954"
                }
            },
            {
                id: "y-axis-downstream",
                type: "linear",
                display: true,
                position: "right",
                stepSize: 0.1,
                fixedStepSize: 0.1,
                gridLines: {
                    color: "rgba(190, 75, 72, 0.2)"
                },
                ticks: {
                    display: true,
                    fontColor: "#BE4B48"
                }
            }
        ]
    }
};

var ctx = document.getElementById("chartID");

var chart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: type,
    data: data,
    options: options
});
```

Comment: Could you share how you are populating the chart and the labels please?